# Azure CLI and SAS Token issue in PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I generated SAS token in Azure Portal and trying to use it to upload files to blob storage:

> az storage blob upload-batch --source ./test --destination '$web' --account-name 'myaccountname' --sas-token '"sp=racwl&st=2022-02-22T17:04:19Z&se=2022-12-23T01:04:19Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=mXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXONfAA%3D"'

But above command gives me following error in PowerShell:

```
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature fields not well formed.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
```

I am literally copying the SAS Token from Azure Portal so how on earth can it be malformed?

Comment: Can you get rid of `''` (single quotes) around your SAS token and try again?

Comment: I already tried that, actually I tried multiple combinations of escape characters. When I get rid of `''` then I get:
`'st' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'se' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
....`

Comment: Can you try removing the double quotes (`"`)? I just tried by removing that and was able to upload the blobs.

Comment: Same error as above, both in old PowerShell and PowerShell 7. I have latest Azure CLI tools. I don't know what can be wrong then..
@Guarav Mantri are you using the SAS token copied directly from Azure Portal?

Comment: Yes. I tried both with and without `?` in front of the SAS Token and it worked in both cases. Can you share the actual signature value?

Comment: Sure:
`az storage blob upload-batch --source ./test --destination 'test' --account-name 'myaccount' --sas-token 'sp=r&st=2022-02-22T18:21:18Z&se=2022-02-23T02:21:18Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=CU%2BHb5T2Y9Os7nRiAGeDyO%2BTFjSxp%2FRdkvsSytFf06c%3D' `

Answer (score 1):

We have ran the same `az storage blob upload-batch` cmdlet in our local environment( which is running with powershell v5.1) & we are able to upload the files from local machine to the storage account as shown in below.

**Here is the cmdlet we have used :**

```
az storage blob upload-batch --account-name <strgAccountName> -s <sourcefilepath> -d 'https://xxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/cont1' --sas-token '<generatedSAStoken from portal>'
```

**Here is the sample Output for reference:**

[image]

**Note:**

To the above cmdlet, We have  tried passing the SAS token with appending(single quote+ question mark) '?' & without passing in single quote's to the `--sas-token` flag in both the cases we are able to upload the files from local machine to Azure storage container.

Comment: The problem we're facing is in powershell core 7.x. Had to use '"<sastoke>"' to get it work.

Comment: Thank you aDisplayName. This fixed my issue with AZCopy and Powershell. I was going crazy because the command syntax that worked in Linux bash wasn't working in Powershell at all, and the error given was an unhelpful "Authorization Failed". I knew the token was good because it worked in Bash.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was wrong, but suddenly it started to work with `'"sastoken"'` format. Thanks for your responses.